# Find all available BookingSlots in a certain timespan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with BookingSlots. Each slot is 15 minutes long.

```
id |     startTime       | userId  | status
-------------------------------------------
1  | 2022-01-01T01:00:00 | 1       | free
-------------------------------------------
2  | 2022-01-01T01:00:00 | 2       | free
-------------------------------------------
3  | 2022-01-01T01:15:00 | 1       | free
-------------------------------------------
4  | 2022-01-01T01:15:00 | 2       | booked
```

I want to find all BookingSlots that are free at a given date for a timespan of 15 minutes grouped by the userId. So when the I would run the query at `01:08:00`, the result should be:

```
id |     startTime       | userId  | status
-------------------------------------------
1  | 2022-01-01T01:00:00 | 1       | free
-------------------------------------------
3  | 2022-01-01T01:15:00 | 1       | free
```

So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "BookingSlot"
WHERE ("startTime" < '2022-01-01T01:08:00'
    AND '2022-01-01T01:08:00' < "startTime" + interval '15 minutes')
    OR("startTime" < timestamp '2022-01-01T01:08:00' + interval '15 minutes'
        AND timestamp '2022-01-01T01:08:00' + interval '15 minutes' < "startTime" + interval '15 minutes')
    AND "status" = 'free'
```

But the query result includes the row with id 2, which does not match the criteria, because the next slot of user 2 is already booked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to filter on `status = 'free` and `startDate` in the right range, and then to select only the `userId` with 2 rows filtered using the clause `HAVING count(*) = 2` :

```
SELECT unnest(array_agg(id)) AS id
     , unnest(array_agg(startTime)) AS startTime
     , userId
     , unnest(array_agg(status)) AS status
 FROM BookingSlots
WHERE status = 'free'
  AND startTime > '2022-01-01T01:08:00' :: timestamp - interval '15 minutes'
  AND startTime <= '2022-01-01T01:08:00' :: timestamp + interval '15 minutes'
GROUP BY userId
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VjBhuuiJ)

Comment: Thank you, this does work with `SELECT userId`, but not with `SELECT *`. With `SELECT *` I always have to include BookingSlot.id in the GROUPY BY clause, but then the result is empty.

Comment: answer updated to fit your expected result